# Create a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of structs and then access the variable in a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I think I got the general idea of how to create and destroy it, but I can not find the way to access each of the objects. Here's how I create it:

```
CCyIsoPktInfo   **arrayOfPointers = new CCyIsoPktInfo*[QueueSize];
for (int i = 0; i < QueueSize; ++i)
{
     arrayOfPointers[i] = new CCyIsoPktInfo[PACKETS_PER_TRANSFER];
}
```

Here's how I destroy it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < QueueSize; ++i)
{
    delete[] arrayOfPointers[i];
}
delete[] arrayOfPointers;
```

But I need to access each nth_Object.status in the array, given the nth_Pointer to that array. So the general idea would be like this:

```
for (int nth_Object = 0; nth_Object < PACKETS_PER_TRANSFER; ++nth_Object)
{
    var[nth_Object] = (*arrayOfPointers[nth_Pointer]).[nth_Object].status;
}
```

I am creating and destroying the them properly? **How to access the elements?**

Comment: FWIW I would suggest either `std::array<std::array<CCyIsoPktInfo, 256>, 64>` or `std::vector<std::vector<CCyIsoPktInfo>>

Comment: Hey @CoryKramer , I am trying to adopt the answer you referenced as duplicate, do not know if I will make it right. Also, I am not familiar with the coding style you suggested.

Comment: What you want is: CCyIsoPktInfo * (* p_to_arr_of_pts) [num]. C++ attempts to follow C's "declaration mimicks usage" pattern. Also, take note that in the line you provided, you do not create an array of pointers to CCyIsoPktInfo objects but instead an array of CCylsoPktInfo objects.

Comment: @Veritas oh, then _num_ is what 64 or 256? And where does the other number goes?

Comment: @CoryKramer you marked my question as a duplicate, but the answers you referenced to do not answer my question completely. What now? I am doomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over your 2D array, you would use a nested loop, for example

```
for (int nth_Object = 0; nth_Object < QueueSize; ++nth_Object)
{
    for (int nth_Pointer = 0; nth_Pointer < PACKETS_PER_TRANSFER; ++ nth_Pointer)
    {
        std::cout << arrayOfPointers[nth_Object][nth_Pointer].status;
    }
}
```

Although for what it's worth, I would recommend using `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocating your own arrays

```
std::vector<std::vector<CCyIsoPktInfo>> data;
```

Then you could iterate like

```
for (auto const& row : data)
{
    for (auto const& element : row)
    {
        std::cout << element.status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cory, for clean up, is it necessary to loop through the array of pointers `delete[] arrayOfPointers[i]` and `delete[] arrayOfPointers` and delete each pointer in the array, or  `delete[] arrayOfPointers` is enough?

Comment: Yes you must clean up the memory as you've shown in your initial post.